# Connect Selenium node to the hub with auth

Tags: selenium, https, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium HUB which requires authentication to reach it through https.

URL:

```
https://xxxxxxxx.com:4444
```

In my nodeConfig.json is set the followings:

```
...
"hubHost":"https://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com",
"hubPort":4444,
....
```

I tried also with the following parameter too:

```
-jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar" -role node -hub "https://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com:4444"
```

When I try to connect the node to the hub the following lines will appear in the console:

```
09:22:55.124 INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://https://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com:4444/grid/register
09:22:56.153 INFO - couldn't register this node : Error sending the registration request.
09:23:02.177 INFO - couldn't register this node : Hub is down or not responding: Connect to https:80 [https/127.0.1.2] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

I think the problem is the http://https:// but I don't know how can I fix it. Could someone please help me, how to connect to the hub with auth?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already tried the url https://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com:4444 manually and found it working; make the below change in the nodeconfig.json

Instead of

```
...
"hubHost":"https://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com",
"hubPort":4444,
....
```

Give

```
...
"hub":"https://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com:4444/grid/register"
....
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the https. I checked the source code and it seems that the selenium grid supports only http. (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/server/test/org/openqa/grid)
Is it possible to set up https without modify the source code?

Comment: Are you able to see the grid console when you give  https ://username:password@xxxxxxxx.com:4444/grid/console?

Comment: Yes I can reach it in the browser.